# Python: Is there an Solution (pivot or groupby) to count dates only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, grouping

is there a simple solution to get the following information? I am new in python and DataFrames and right currently I fail to solve this issue.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

d1 = date(2020,11,23)
d2 = date(2020,11,24)
d3 = date(2020,11,25)

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'Area': ['Area_A', 'Area_A', 'Area_B'], 
                        'Sub_Area': ['Area_A1', 'Area_A2', 'Area_B1'],
                        'Milestone_1': [d1, d2, '-'], 
                        'Milestone_2': [d3, '-', '-']}) 
df_test 
------------------------------------
     Area Sub_Area Milestone_1 Milestone_2
0  Area_A  Area_A1  2020-11-23  2020-11-25
1  Area_A  Area_A2  2020-11-24           -
2  Area_B  Area_B1           -           -
------------------------------------
```

I need to estimate for each Area the latest Milestone this information:

1. Amount of subareas,
2. Recent milestone of each subarea and
3. Amount of recent milestones for each per area.

The final table or data frame should look like this:

```
------------------------------------
     Area  Sum_of_Sub_Area Sum_of_Milestone_1 Sum_Milestone_2
0  Area_A  2               2                  1
1  Area_B  1               0                  0
------------------------------------
```

Can somebody help me out?

My first try with `pivot_table` doesnt provide the right solution, because I only need to count the dates. `Area_B` has no date in any `Milestone`:

```
df_test.pivot_table(values=['Sub_Area', 'Milestone_1', 'Milestone_2'], 
                                      index=['Area'],
                                      aggfunc=['count'],
                                      fill_value=0)

------------------------------------
             count
       Milestone_1 Milestone_2 Sub_Area
Area
Area_A           2           2        2
Area_B           1           1        1
------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used other method than pivot -

```
areas = df_test["Area"].unique().tolist()
est_by_area = pd.DataFrame(index = areas)
est_by_area["Sum_of_Sub_Area"] = df_test["Area"].value_counts().to_frame()
df_test[["Milestone_1", "Milestone_2"]] = df_test[["Milestone_1", "Milestone_2"]].replace("-", np.nan)
est_by_area["Sum_of_Milestone_1"] = df_test.groupby("Area")["Milestone_1"].count().to_frame()
est_by_area["Sum_of_Milestone_2"] = df_test.groupby("Area")["Milestone_2"].count().to_frame()
```

I will go over what I did here:

First I created unique list of the areas.
than I created new dataframe named "est_by_area" while its index is the areas list I created before.
After that, I assigned the value_counts() method to the "Sum_of_Sub_Area" column, the value_counts() method gives you the unique values and the number of times that they appear.
After that I had a problem with the dates, I had 2 columns "Milestone_1" and "Milestone_2" with mixed dates and strings contains "-" for empty dates.
What I did here is I converted empty dates to np.nan so when I use methods on it, it won't count the empty dates ("-").
Lastly, I grouped the df by "Area" column and counted the times every column has values and assigned it to our new dataframe.

Result:

```
    Sum_of_Sub_Area     Sum_of_Milestone_2
Area_A  2               1
Area_B  1               0
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about consistency of data going into `agg()`

1. replaced `-` with `np.nan` then made sure *Milestone* columns are still `datetime64`
2. simple `groupby()` and `agg()` with *count* gets what you want

```
from datetime import date

d1 = date(2020,11,23)
d2 = date(2020,11,24)
d3 = date(2020,11,25)

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'Area': ['Area_A', 'Area_A', 'Area_B'], 
                        'Sub_Area': ['Area_A1', 'Area_A2', 'Area_B1'],
                        'Milestone_1': [d1, d2, '-'], 
                        'Milestone_2': [d3, '-', '-']}) 

dfc = df_test.replace({"-":np.nan}).astype({c:"datetime64" for c in df_test.columns if "Mile" in c})\
    .groupby("Area").agg({"Milestone_1":"count","Milestone_2":"count"})

print(dfc.to_string())
```

**output**

```
        Milestone_1  Milestone_2
Area                            
Area_A            2            1
Area_B            0            0
```